# How do I automatically create a new element upon submission of an input in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on my first react js project as a task list. It has a text input value which's value is passed into a function on submit to update a list element. My question is this, I want to make it that on submit it creates a new

element which holds the value of the state. I have first tried using an object when it gave me an error that objects cannot be used for a child element. Which I opted by changing the state into an array but it still does not create a new element like I intended. Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Tests extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      object: [],
    };
    this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  updateInputValue(evt) {
    this.setState({
      value: evt.target.value,
    });
  }

  submit() {
    this.setState({
      object: this.state.value,
      value: "",
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for="text">Text 1</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          label="text"
          onChange={(evt) => this.updateInputValue(evt)}
          onSubmit={this.submit}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.submit} style={{ height: 50, width: 60 }}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <ul>
          <li>{this.state.object}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tests;

ReactDOM.render(<Tests />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

If there are any suggestions on how to improve this code I wrote I will read them and try to adjust my code to be better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially overwriting the value of `object` on your `setState`. What you need to do, is keep the old array, and append the last item. Using spread syntax:

```js
submit() {
  this.setState({
    object : [...this.state.object, this.state.value],
    value  : "",
  });
}
```

This creates a new Array with your new item appended. Be careful not to mutate the state (in other words, change `this.state`):

```js
// the above code is essentially doing this:
const newObject = [...this.state.object, this.state.value];
this.setState({ object: newObject });

//  buggy version! This is mutating the state:
this.state.object.push(this.state.value);
```

On your render, you need to render a `map` of objects:

```js
<ul>
   { this.state.object.map(item => <li>{ item }</li>) }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend I think that might be a part of the problem, however now upon submission only appends the one <li> element instead of creating a brand new one

Comment: I just edited my answer. That is because you are rendering the array itself, what you need to do is render a map of each elements of the `object` array.